# Two way databinding in Angular when using method in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

Is there a way to tell angular that a particular function in `$scope` is dependant on some other fields in `$scope`? I would like to hide some functionality in data model, for example:

```
$scope.user = {
   name: "John",
   surname: "Smith",
   getUsername: function() {
      return [this.name, this.surname].join(' ');
   }
}
```

Then I would like to use `$scope.user.getUsername()` in the html template, but when I change `$scope.user.name`, template doesn't refresh. Is the a way to tell angular that this function is dependant on other fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, It turned out that Angular is doing it automatically but I was changing it it without using `$apply`.